# SQL Server Service Broker Column Names and Types?

Tags: sql-server-2008, service-broker

I have a Service Broker (MSSQL 2008) queue with many thousands of messages. To do some forensics on the messages, I have selected the top 10,000 messages into a ##temp table. I have successfully BCP'd out the global temp table into a file. Now I need to BCP it into a local MSSQL instance, into a new table. The table has to have the same schema as the queue.

However, I can't seem to figure out what the structure of the new table should be.

I did this:

```
 exec tempdb..sp_columns '##x'
```

And then tried to make a new table with a Create Table statement, but BCP-in does not seem to work.

I figure that the schema of a queue must be in MSDB somewhere, or there has to be a way to clearly get the column Types of a Service Broker queue.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have it in a temp table and have appropriate permissions.

```
SElECT TOP 0 * INTO NewTable FROM #TempTable
```

Then use SSMS to script it